# Ways to put user roles in a database

Tags: mysql, database

What would be the most efficient way to store a users role in the database?

For example the rights would be like this:

There should be rights to see a page:

- **Page1**
- **Page2**
- **Page3**
- **Page4**

So in the case above you should be allowed to either have the right to see **Page1** and **Page2** but also just **Page3**

You can

- Delete post
- Create post
- Edit post

on just **Page2**

All these possibilities of combinations should have their own role.

Now I dont know how to store this in a table.

I thought about creating a table like this:

```
role | page1 | page2 | page3 | page4 | page5 | page6 | delete | create | edit |
role1| yes   | yes   | no    | no    | no    | no    | yes    | no     | yes  |
```

But I think there's way too many combinations to use this so there must be a better/efficient/easier way to do this.

I've also seen people use bit wise operations:

```
const read           = 1;
const write          = 2;
const append         = 4;
const delete         = 8;
const deleteContents = 16;
const readPerm       = 32;
const changePerm     = 64;
/* shortcuts */
const fullControl    = 127; 
const noControl      = 0;
```

and then link them to a role
but I've heard that's awfull to use.

So my question is:

What options do I have and what are the up and downsides of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an option, you can create two tables:

Table 1: user ID<>Role ID mapping

Table 2: Role<>Page configuration with the following columns: Page ID | Role ID | View | Delete | Create | Edit

This way you are not limited to the number of pages

Comment: You know what, this is actually a really good solution. At least I think. I'm gonna try to make the tables and see if it makes sense.

Comment: I agree, however you can also make the permissions pivot off the role, so you can add other permissions without having to alter the table. So you have `users <-> users_roles <-> roles <-> roles_permissions <-> permissions`.